# Adding nothing to a list

Tags: list, null, erlang

:)

I want to write DRY erlang code but I have a problem. I've got a record like this

```
-record(person, {firstname, lastname, phones=[], emails=[]}).
```

And I use it to create an adress book which is simple lists of persons. Then I want to call a function:

```
updatePersonsInfo(FName,LName,Phone, Email,[Old = #person{firstname = FName, lastname = LName} | T]) ->
  UpdatedPhonesList = #person.phones ++ [Phone],
  UpdatedEmailsList = #person.emails ++ [Email],
  [Old#person{phones= UpdatedPhonesList, emails = UpdatedEmailsList}] ++ T;
```

And I want to call this function but I want to add only an email. Something like this:

```
updatePersonsInfo(FName,LName, "",Email,Book);
```

But then I receive an error:

```
** exception error: bad argument
 in operator  ++/2
    called as 4 ++ []
```

So I guess this is just a matter of adding nothing to list. Of course I can split this function to: updatePersonsEmail and updatePersonsPhone, but the logic of these two functions will be the same which will make my code ugly.

Any ideas? I tried to use null atom, or _ , or even [] but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#person.phones`  doesnot return old phone list. It returns just number of 'phones' field in the 'person' record.. 
That is why erlang complains about 4++[]

To get old phone list, you have to use  Old#person.phones

Comment: Of coures! thanks mate, sorry to bother you with syntax error